# Keras and TensorFlow: I'm getting an InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I am just starting out with Keras and TensorFlow and I have started by following the tutorial  (https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/)

Unfortunately when I run the finished code (I'm using Anaconda - not sure if this is relevant) I get the following error:

Here is the code:

```
# Create your first MLP in Keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("D:\Applications\Python Apps\pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Here is the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 10 values, but the requested shape has 0
[[Node: training/Adam/gradients/loss/dense_3_loss/Mean_1_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/loss/dense_3_loss/Mean_1_grad/truediv"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](training/Adam/gradients/loss/dense_3_loss/mul_grad/Sum, training/Adam/gradients/loss/dense_3_loss/Mean_1_grad/DynamicStitch/_75)]]
```

Here is an image of the entire thing which is a bit easier to read - https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7qUU.jpg

If someone is able to assist with this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks
Glen

Comment: Is that an image of the code or error ? They [discourage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)  that. In fact some corporare proxies like mine block them.You can include enough details in the question directly.

Comment: Hi Glen , I don't often use Keras but the code looks okay... could you please print X.shape and Y.shape and give the result

Comment: @abcdaire I get the following:
X =(768, 8)
Y = (768,)

Comment: I just copied your code and tried executing it. I trained successfully and didn't get any errors. Did you check your dataset?

Comment: @timedacorn I am using this one - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv

Comment: It was a bug in TensorFlow version 1.09. Moving to 1.10 fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in TensorFlow version 1.09. Moving to 1.10 fixed it